# jQuery getScript not running fail method on connection refused

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to account for a script not loading as it might be blocked by China's firewall. So I edited my hosts file to direct google.com and www.google.com to 127.0.0.1.

When I run the following

```
$.getScript('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js').done(function(){
    console.log('done');
}).fail(function(){
    console.log('fail');
});
```

I get `done` when not blocked but I don't get the `fail` when it is blocked. I do see the connection refused however in the console when trying to load the script.

Am I missing something in the documentation? How can I test or run a fallback if the script fails to load. Why is the fail not firing? I've tried all manner of stuff to get it to work but can't figure it out.

I tried writing it long hand but to no avail as well.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js",
    dataType: 'script',
    error: function(){
        console.log('test');
    },
    cache: false,
    complete: function(){
        console.log('complete');
    },
    success: function(){
        console.log('success');
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm open to testing the connection in another way, but this just seemed the most straight forward, or so I thought.

Comment: When i change the datatype to HTML it appears to handle the error correctly but I get the cross-domain error for obvious reasons. For testing purposes however it seemed to work. So why when it's script does the `fail` not trigger and how can I load the freaking script on a normal case but fail if it actually fails to load at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I missing something in docs?

Yes. Note in `error` description:

> Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and
>   cross-domain JSONP requests.

Comment: I went with the timeout method. I literally read the docs several times and for some reason literally as I read it, it's like it just didn't make sense to me.